# Update with MAX() in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

The code bellow works great but...

How can I use Update with a MAX() function in the same statement?

Something like: UPDATE Msg SET myTime=NOW() WHERE user='username' AND myTime=max(myTimp)

```
SELECT @myId:=(SELECT id FROM Msg
WHERE myTime=(SELECT MAX(myTime) FROM Msg
WHERE user='username'));

UPDATE Msq SET myTime=NOW() 
WHERE id=@myId;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  UPDATE Msg
     SET myTime=NOW()
   WHERE user='username'
ORDER BY myTime DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @Unreason: query for oracle will be almost the same ;-) (but with `rownum = 1` instead of `LIMIT`)

Comment: @Alqin: stop thinking about "tricks" - it is a common query, nothing special.